# Python: How to time script from beginning to end?

Tags: python, time, timing

I've created a script which processes files and returns the size of each file in bytes. The time it takes is dependent on how large the directory is that you scan.

At the top of my script, I placed in:

```
now = "\n", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
print "Started processing data at:",now
```

and at the bottom:

```
finish = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
print "Finished processing data at: ", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
difference = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()) - finish.strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
```

I didn't think it was going to work, but I hope you understand my logic. I want to subtract the `now` hours, minutes & seconds from the `finish` hours, minutes & seconds.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Invoke the script by saying: `time python script.py`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try datetime module.

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
```

Later

```
difference = datetime.now() - start
```

Comment: I hit submit prematurely.

Comment: You may want "datetime.now()" instead of "datetime.not()" ;)

Comment: And `datetime.now()` instead of `now()`.

Comment: Done. That was embarrassing.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up guys, that was a bit confusing at first :-) Cheers.

Comment: Can someone just confirm, the 'difference = datetime.now() - start' is 0:00:01.043000. Is that Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Miliseconds

Answer (score 2):

I would say to use something like:

```
import time
begin = time.time()
#your code here
end = time.time()
execution_time = end-begin
```

Comment: This is often the easiest when you just want seconds of clock time since something started. Who ever really needs the date...